# Error Date type (Google visualization)

Tags: javascript, google-visualization

This is my code for displaying the chart

```
$scope.course_chart = function(response){
        var data2 = new google.visualization.DataTable();
        data2.addColumn('date', 'pv_date');
        data2.addColumn('string', 'pageviews');

        _.each(response.result.rows, function(item){

            var formattedDate = item[0].slice(0, 4) + ", " + item[0].slice(4, 6) + ", " + item[0].slice(6, 8);

            var date_format = new Date(formattedDate);
            date_format = $filter('date')(date_format);

            data2.addRow([
                date_format,
                item[1]
            ]);

        });

        var chart = new google.visualization.AreaChart(document.querySelector('#course_chart'));
        chart.draw(data2, options2);

};

google.load('visualization', '1', {packages:['corechart'], callback: $scope.course_chart});
```

My date_format value is **Sep 27, 2016**

what is the requirement output for this data type "date" in google visualization?

Comment: I know nothing about that library but I'd expect you could provide dates as dates (not text). In JavaScript that means `Date` objects.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if you have column with data type: `'date'`
then you must pass a date object --> `new Date()`

you can use any of the javascript [date contructors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date)

such as...

`new Date(2016, 8, 26)`
remember in javascript, months are zero based (8 = Sept)

or...

`new Date('09/26/2016')`
this creates the date from a string and **does not** set the format when displayed

adding rows to the data table...

```
data2.addColumn('date', 'pv_date');
data2.addRow(new Date(2016, 8, 26));
```

if you already have the date formatted, you can use object notation when adding rows
(`v` = value, `f` = formatted value)...

```
data2.addRow({
  v: new Date(2016, 8, 26)
  f: 'Sep 26, 2016'
});
```

you can also use the [`DateFormat`](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/reference#dateformat) provided by google

```
data2.addRow(new Date(2016, 8, 26));

var formatDate = new google.visualization.DateFormat({
  pattern: 'MMM d, yyyy'
});
formatDate.format(data2, 0);
```

finally, you can provide raw dates and let the axis format the dates
i.e. `hAxis.format: 'MMM d, yyyy'`...

**here are a few examples using each scenario...**

**1.** use `hAxis.format`

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  callback: function () {
    var data2 = new google.visualization.DataTable();
    data2.addColumn('date', 'pv_date');
    data2.addColumn('number', 'pageviews');

    data2.addRows([
      [new Date(2016, 8, 26), 100],
      [new Date(2016, 8, 27), 101]
    ]);

    var options = {
      hAxis: {
        format: 'MMM d, yyyy'
      }
    };

    var chart = new google.visualization.AreaChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
    chart.draw(data2, options);
  },
  packages:['corechart']
});
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="chart_div"></div>
```

**2.**  use `DateFormat`

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  callback: function () {
    var data2 = new google.visualization.DataTable();
    data2.addColumn('date', 'pv_date');
    data2.addColumn('number', 'pageviews');

    data2.addRows([
      [new Date(2016, 8, 26), 100],
      [new Date(2016, 8, 27), 101]
    ]);

    var formatDate = new google.visualization.DateFormat({
      pattern: 'MMM d, yyyy'
    });
    formatDate.format(data2, 0);

    var chart = new google.visualization.AreaChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
    chart.draw(data2);
  },
  packages:['corechart']
});
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="chart_div"></div>
```

**3.**  use Object notation `{v: , f:}`

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  callback: function () {
    var data2 = new google.visualization.DataTable();
    data2.addColumn('date', 'pv_date');
    data2.addColumn('number', 'pageviews');

    data2.addRows([
      [{v: new Date(2016, 8, 26), f: 'Sep 26, 2016'}, 100],
      [{v: new Date(2016, 8, 27), f: 'Sep 27, 2016'}, 101]
    ]);

    var chart = new google.visualization.AreaChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
    chart.draw(data2);
  },
  packages:['corechart']
});
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="chart_div"></div>
```

also, for `AreaChart`, the columns after the first should be of type: `'number'` -- not `'string'`