# Displaying formatted time on Y axis in Google Charts

Tags: javascript, charts, google-visualization

Here's some example data:

> Best running time on 1000 ft depending on age:
>
> ```
>                | 7 yrs | 8 yrs | 9 yrs | ...
> --------------------------------------------
> time, seconds  |  100  |  80   |  70   |
> ```

I want time (on Y axis) to displayed as a formatted value, not just plain number. This could be anything readable like 01:23.  Failed to find any working example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `'timeofday'` column type for y-axis

From the docs --> [Working with Timeofday](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/datesandtimes#working-with-timeofday)

See following working snippet...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  callback: drawChart,
  packages:['corechart']
});

function drawChart() {
  var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ['', ''],
    [7, [0, 1, 40]],
    [8, [0, 1, 20]],
    [9, [0, 1, 10]],
    [10, [0, 0, 59]]
  ]);

  var container = document.getElementById('chart_div');
  var chart = new google.visualization.ScatterChart(container);
  chart.draw(data);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="chart_div"></div>
```

Comment: although not `'timeofday'` -- see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39862037/5090771) for adding custom axis labels using `ticks`

Comment: I've updated your code snippet, because it was not really working... or I did not explain the question well

Comment: Oh! Now I get it. Google Charts API automatically detects the column type and treats the inner array as time