# Accessing hAxis ticks on Google Timeline Chart

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to set custom date formatting on  Google Timeline Chart. I have [working examples for other chart types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28764143/formatting-timezone-of-google-charts-datetime-axis-labels) and [documentation](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/linechart#configuration-options), but this does not seem to work for timelines.

```
                        for (var i = 0, len = container.clientWidth / 90; i <= len; i++) {
                            var realDate = START + (END - START) * i / len;
                            ticks.push({
                                v: new Date(realDate * 1000),
                                f: moment.unix(realDate).format(formatStr)
                            });
                        }

                        chart.draw(dataTable, {
                            hAxis: {
                                minValue: st,
                                maxValue: en,
                                ticks: ticks
                            },
                        });
```

The not working part seems to be

```
                            ticks.push({
                                v: new Date(realDate * 1000),
                                f: moment.unix(realDate).format(formatStr)
                            });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `hAxis.format` option config to setup the time format in hAxis ticks.